# How to remove an element from an array dynamically? React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

There are two components, I want to implement an element array using the `useContext` hook, but when the button is clicked, the element is not removed, but on the contrary, there are more of them. Tell me what is wrong here. I would be very grateful!

First component:

```
import React from 'react';
import CartItem from './CartItem';
import Context from '../Context'; 

function Cart() {
    let sum = 0;
    let arrPrice = [];
    let [products, setProducts] = React.useState([]);
    let loacalProsucts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));

    if(loacalProsucts === null) {
        return(
            <div className="EmptyCart">
                <h1>Cart is empty</h1>
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        {loacalProsucts.map(item => products.push(item))}
        {loacalProsucts.map(item => arrPrice.push(JSON.parse(item.total)))}
    }

    for(let i in arrPrice) {
        sum += arrPrice[i];
    }

    function removeItem(id) {
        setProducts(
            products.filter(item => item.id !== id)
        )
    }

    return(
        <Context.Provider value={{removeItem}}>
            <div className="Cart">
                <h1>Your purchases:</h1>
                <CartItem products = {products} />
                <h1>Total: {sum}$</h1>
            </div>
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}
```

Second component:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Context from '../Context';

function CartList({products}) {
    const {removeItem} = useContext(Context);
    return(
        <div className="CartList">
            <img src={products.image} />
            <h2>{products.name}</h2>
            <h3 className="CartInfo">{products.kg}kg.</h3>
            <h2 className="CartInfo">{products.total}$</h2>
            <button className="CartInfo" onClick={() => removeItem(products.id)}>&times;</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CartList;
```

Component with a context:

```
import React from 'react';

const Context = React.createContext();

export default Context;
```

Comment: All the code that is in your render loop, like `products.push(item)` will run every time the component renders. That's what React hooks are for.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the comment above ^^

It's almost always a mistake to have initialization expressions inside your render loop (ie, outside of hooks). You'll also want to avoid mutating your local state, that's why useState returns a setter.

Totally untested:

```
function Cart() {
  let [sum, setSum] = React.useState();
  const loacalProsucts = useMemo(() => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products')));
  // Init products with local products if they exist
  let [products, setProducts] = React.useState(loacalProsucts || []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // This is actually derived state so the whole thing
    // could be replaced with
    // const sum = products.reduce((a, c) => a + c?.total, 0);
    setSum(products.reduce((a, c) => a + c?.total, 0));
  }, [products]);

  function removeItem(id) {
    setProducts(
      products.filter(item => item.id !== id)
    )
  }

...
```